# Is there any way to solve this error need some good insights

Tags: python, django, django-models

My error is :-

```
groups.Groups.members: (fields.E303) Reverse query name for 'groups.Groups.members' clashes with field name 'auth.User.groups'.
        HINT: Rename field 'auth.User.groups', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'groups.Groups.members'.
```

My code:-

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.text import slugify
import misaka
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

# Create your models here.

class Groups(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    slug = models.SlugField(allow_unicode=True,unique = True)
    description = models.TextField(blank = True,default = '')
    description_html = models.TextField()
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User,through = 'GroupMember') 
   
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def save(self,*args,**Kwargs):
        self.slug = self.slugify(self.name)
        self.description_html = self.misaka(self.description)
        super().save(*args,**Kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('groups:single',Kwargs={'slug':self.slug})

    class Meta():
        ordering = ['name']


class GroupMember(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Groups,related_name='membership',on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name = 'user_group',on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    class Meta():
        unique_together=['group','user']
```

Comment: This error should only come when you don't use `through='GroupMember'`. Are you getting this with the current code you showed here?

Comment: yes because when i created groups app and wrote down this code while migrating i got this error

Comment: Migrating with the through model?

Comment: i am using python manage.py through my project name and still getting this error

Comment: it worked i removed through and used related_name then the error has been gone